# Hebrew dictionary remove all non - hebrew characters

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a Hebrew dictionary

and patram after something that removes all things that are not Hebrew characters

```
from unidecode import unidecode
import random
import re

random = (random.randint(1000, 2000))

n = (input("HebrewFileName?:"))

with open(""+str(n)+".txt", encoding='utf-8') as fname:
    text = fname.read()
    res = re.sub('[!,*)@|#%(&$_?.^]', '', text)
    lst = list(set(res.split()))
    str1 = ' '.join(str(e) for e in lst)
    lines = str1.split(' ')
    lines1 = list(filter(lambda w: not re.match(r'[a-zA-Z]+', w), lines))
    text1 = ("\n".join(lines1))
    text2 = ''.join(filter(lambda x: not x.isdigit(), text1))

    print(text2, file=open(""+str(random)+"-.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8'))
    print("done")
```

how could i do that? please give an example in the code

for example this

test = "כַּחֲצִי" if it is Hebrew to write to the file

if there are not all Hebrew characters not to add

example
input text
test = "כַּחֲצִי"
output is same כַּחֲצִי

if have non hebrew words delete
test = "כַּtestחֲצִי"
this delete output is "" none

```
 alphabet = {   "א","אִ","ב","בּ","ג","ד","ה","ם","ו","וּ","ן","ז","ח","חָ","ט","י","כ","ָך","ל","מ","נ","ס","ע","פ","ף","צ","ץ","ק","ר","ש","ת"} I'm basically looking for something that removes all the characters except these and leaves spaces
```

Comment: `res = re.sub('[!,t*)@|#%(&$_?.^]', '', text) `   is there something similar where I mark the characters that are not removed and the rest to be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alphabet = " אאִבבּגדהםווּןזחחָטיכָךלמנסעפףצץקרשת" 
def letters_only(source):
    result = ""
    for i in source.lower():
        if i in alphabet:
            result += i
    return result


with open(""+str("random")+".txt", encoding='utf-8') as fname:
    text = fname.read()
    test=(letters_only(text))
    print(test, file=open(""+str("random")+"-.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8'))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

An older question, but will give alternatives for future reference.

Given in OP, that "כַּחֲצִי" should return כַּחֲצִי , and "כַּtestחֲצִי" should return an empty string.

If is possible to use the regex module to match script using `\p{Hebrew}`. Likewise it is possible to use the unicodedataplus module, a drop in replacement for unicodedata module, which has the method `unicodedataplus.script()`.

1. Using Unicodedataplus

```py
import unicodedataplus as ud

test1 = "כַּחֲצִי"
test2 = "כַּtestחֲצִי"

def isHebrew(text):
    if all([True if ud.script(char) == 'Hebrew' else False for char in text]):
        return text
    return ""
  
print(isHebrew(test1))
# כַּחֲצִי
print(isHebrew(test2))
#
```

2. Using regex

```py
import regex as re

pattern = re.compile(r'\p{Hebrew}+')
def isHebrew(text):
    m = re.fullmatch(pattern, text)
    if m:
        return m.group()
    return ''

print(isHebrew(test1))
# כַּחֲצִי
isHebrew(test2)
#
```